# Locking/Unlocking cells excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, case

I have a code i am trying to apply. The **Objective** of the macro is that when the relevant cell is double clicked a time stamp is applied then cell is locked from editing. If cells need to be edited then a password needs to be applied.

The **problem** is that i am not able to get the locking of the cells and password to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                    .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                    .Value2 = .Locked = True
                     .Value2 = ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Test"
                    End Select
                  End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do the job? Not sure what you want to happen if someone wants to change a filled cell. You could have a separate SelectionChange or Change event to handle that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

With Target
    If .Column = 4 Then
        Select Case .Row
            Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30 - 35, 37, 38, 40, 42 - 44, 54 - 56, 58, 59, 61 - 65
                ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Test", userinterfaceonly:=True
                .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                .Locked = True
        End Select
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks that it works to lock the cells. I would have assume if i double click would request for a password since it is locked.

Comment: So somebody double clicks on a cell, you want the date etc added, but then you want them to be able to go back and edit the cell?

Comment: A user will double click on the cell  and it will be locked. But a different user whose is responsible for amending the file should be able to double click on that protected cell and enter a password to unlock the cell.

Comment: @James is it neccesary that this responsible user enters the password?, why don´t just use SJR code after a user validation so it enables the cell automatically to make modifications ?

Comment: @jsanchezs that's an idea. Can u explain that.  So once it's time stamped  & locked. How would I unlock the cell.